# UItableView accessoryButton error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, row

Hello I have a problem

```
I implement this method
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
     NSLog(@"Row=%i",indexPath.row);
     }
```

If I run the app and tab on the DisclosureButton of the second row the output is "0". If I tab on the second row (not the DisclosureButton) the output is "1" (as aspected). The bug is only one the second row, all other rows work fine.

How can I fix this problem? 
thanks

Comment: Tapping the cell itself (not the accessory) shouldn't even fire this event, so there's some more going on.

Comment: make sure your tapping the correct cell's DisclosureButton..are you using sectioned tableview?